# Is it possible to Delete JSON key value pair with UpdateRecord processor in Apache Nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

is it possible to remove a key / value pair with the UpdateRecord processor?
For example

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "John",
    "age": 26
}
```

to

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "John"
}
```

What do I have to put in processor configuration as property and value?

Thanks

Comment: for sure you can do it with Jolt (json-to-json transformation). not sure about updaterecord because what you want to do - it's like deleting a column..

Comment: Do you need to delete any appearance of key 'age' and its value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QueryRecord` to filter out the fields you do not need.

1. Add a `QueryRecordProcessor`
2. Set `Record Reader` to `JSONTreeReader`
3. Set `Record Writer` to `JSONRecordSetWriter`
4. Add a property `filter_id_name` and the value field set to SQL `SELECT id, name FROM FLOWFILE`
5. The `filter_id_name` relation now contains modified content. Use the relation for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

You could change a JsonRecordSetWriter controller settings to:
Schema Access Strategy = Use 'Schema Text' Property

Before the UpdateRecord set attribute  avro.schema =

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "TestObject",
    "namespace": "ca.dataedu",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "id",
        "type": ["int"]
    }, {
        "name": "name",
        "type": ["null", "string"],
        "default": null
    }]
}
```